# How to update my Recyclerview using kotlin android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have an actitvity with Recyclerview which display data. Now I want to update my `RecyclerView` once got a new data.For now each time I close and reopen my app the new data will be displayed. but i want it without close to update my view.

I have tried this,

but nothing will work,

```
fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection, mainActivity: MainActivity) {

        val cc: Context = mainActivity.applicationContext

        if(adapter.count < 2) {
            if (incoming.equals(OUTGOING)) {
                val gson = Gson()
                val gson1 = GsonBuilder().create()
                val model = it
                val IT = gson.toJson(model)

                val pref = cc.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefSend", 0)
                val editor = pref.edit()
                editor.putString("NEWIT_SEND", IT)
                editor.apply()

                adapter.addFragment(SendingFragment(),"SEND")
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else if (incoming.equals(INCOMING)) {
                val gson = Gson()
                val gson1 = GsonBuilder().create()
                val model = it
                val IT = gson.toJson(model)

                val pref = cc.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefRec", 0)
                val editor = pref.edit()
                editor.putString("NEWIT_REC", IT)
                editor.apply()
                adapter.addFragment(ReceiveFragment(), "RECEIVE")
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            viewPager.adapter = adapter
        }
    }


class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager)
    {
        private val mFragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList: ArrayList<String>  = ArrayList<String>()

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragmentList.size
        }


        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
            var fragment: Fragment? = null
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = SendingFragment()
            } else if (position == 1) {
                fragment = ReceiveFragment()
            }
            return fragment
        }


        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }

        override fun getItemPosition(fragItem: Any): Int {
            var position = 0
            if (fragItem is ReceiveFragment) {
                position = 0
            } else if (fragItem is SendingFragment) {
                position = 1
            }
            return if (position >= 0) position else PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
        }
    }

**Framgnet.kt**





class ReceiveFragment: Fragment()
    {

        private var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null

        fun fromJson(jsonString: String, type: Type): Any {
            return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type)
        }

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

            val pref = context!!.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefRec", 0)
            val mFragIT = pref.getString("NEWIT_REC", "")

            val NewIT = fromJson(mFragIT,
                    object : TypeToken<List<TransactionEntity>>() {

                    }.type) as List<TransactionEntity>

            val activity = activity  as MainActivity
            val myAppDatabaseData = activity.getAppDatabaseData()
            val myNetwrk = activity.getNwtwrkData()

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receive_fragment, container, false)
            val recyclerView = rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.transaction_recycler_in) as RecyclerView
            linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            recyclerView.adapter = TransactionRecyclerAdapter(NewIT,myAppDatabaseData,TransactionAdapterDirection.INCOMING,myNetwrk)
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            return rootView
        }

    }
```

I have tried this, **mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: whenever you receive new set of data, add them in the arraylist, then pass that list to adapter & then notifyDataSetChanged should be called. and notifyDataSetChanged should be called from your fragment

Comment: any example link plz

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/recylerview-list-adapter-template-in-kotlin-6b9814201458

Answer (score 9):

If you want to update data from activity/fragment than you can make one function inside adapter as below:

```
 public void update(ArrayList<String> modelList){
        //string arraylist is for example pass your data
        // replace your adapter data with argument data
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

For kotlin:

```
fun update(modelList:ArrayList<String){
   myList = modelList
   myAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Call this function from activity/fragment as below :

```
 mAdapter.update(response.getList());
```

Comment: @Karthikeyan IMHO way better if you figure it out by yourself, than asking someone else to make homework or work for you. You'll learn so much more this way!

Comment: @Karthikeyan sure I can If I have full code of adapter and the fragment code where you call your adapter second time. Because in general when there is change/ new api call is made then only we make change in adapter's data

Comment: @Alessio Then what is the point of SO? The OP didn't say "How do I do this?" without even trying themselves. The person is clearly learning. The person posted their code. They asked for help. This is the very reason SO exists. So, what should they have done differently, in your not-so-humble opinion?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva I agree with you, that's why I gave my own answer to Karthikeyan before I added comments. Generally speaking I still don't think to paste 300 lines of code and then saying "this doesn't work, find me my problem and possibly solve it too" is the way to use SO. I think whoever ask a question should reduce the code to the minimum, so that we can help her out

Comment: The people who visit SO have varying levels of experience. I've been programming for 30+ years, but I'm still a beginner in many respects, because I'm working in new languages or new environments. While I understand the need and how to reduce a problem to its bare minimum (which often resolves the issue before I post), others may have started programming only last week, following a Udemy course or the Google Developer labs, etc. They don't have that experience, so they post everything.

Comment: @Alessio I agree with you that the more the OP can do themselves, the better in the long run. However, I've also seen numerous posts where someone tried to post "only what's needed" only to have many commenters say that they didn't post enough. So, it often feels like a total crap shoot in terms of what's "too much" and what's "not enough". I just think there are so many factors which cannot be adequately accounted for, so I tend to assume that the user is new and respond accordingly. I try *not* to belittle someone or call out a question for being too broad or posting too much code.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva me too I always try to assume it's a new beginner, and I always try to answer politely which is very important. Still, and without saying is the case for this question, sometimes I perceive people on SO come to just have their homework done by us, which is not healthy for SO itself but also for them, mainly, as the point from their pov is (and must be) to will to learn.

Comment: @Alessio Yes, indeed. I agree with that, though personally I haven't seen many cases of actual students posting homework questions. Either that or they're masking it well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a function in your ItemAdapter:

```
/**
 * Refresh the whole data set of items.
 */
fun refreshDataset() {
    mDataset = parseItems(mAppCtx)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

and then, any time you receive a new set of data, you can call such function directly.

Comment: what is parseItems(). i am new to android can u exaplin little bit more from my code

Comment: copying your own code with project specific variables and methods is pretty useless

Comment: @Karthikeyan I assume you're familiar with [at least the basics of RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), whereas your views are decoupled from their content. mDataset is the reference to your data set (in my case an Item[] for instance), mAppCtx is a reference to the application context that you will need to retrieve shared resources like strings etc, and parseItems() is the function that you'll use to transform your pojo into your internal dataset ready to be shown on UI (for instance you will need a subset of your plain pojo one).

Comment: @TimCastelijns I didn't copy my code. Such method is very generic and very abstract, and it's what is needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do in more Kotlin style do like this:

1) Create an abstract class for Adapter:

```
 abstract class BaseRecyclerAdapter<Type, ViewHolder : BaseViewHolder<Type>>(list: List<Type> = mutableListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

   var items: MutableList<Type> = list.toMutableList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size
    enter code here
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(items[position]) }
```

2) Create an abstract class for ViewHolder:

```
 abstract class BaseViewHolder<in T>(override val containerView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), LayoutContainer {

    abstract fun bind(item: T) }
```

3) How to use:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() { private var adapter: MyAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        //This is your data which you set first time
        val initData = mutableListOf<String>()
        adapter = MyAdapter(initData)
        myRecyclerView.layoutManager = adapter
        myRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }
    // Call this function when you need to update adapter
    private fun notifyAdapter(list: MutableList<String>){
        adapter.items = list 
    }}
```

Create MyAdapter:

```
 private class MyAdapter(list: MutableList<String>) : BaseRecyclerAdapter<String, ViewHolder>(list) {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder.newInstance(parent)

    }
```

Create ViewHolder for MyAdapter:

```
private class ViewHolder(containerView: View) : BaseViewHolder<String>(containerView) {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(parent: ViewGroup) = ViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item))
    }

    override fun bind(item: String) {
        title.text = item
    }}
```

Create item for ViewHolder:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

If you have any questions please ask

Answer (score 1):

You should try `LiveData`

> LiveData is a data holder class that can be observed within a given
>   lifecycle. This means that an Observer can be added in a pair with a
>   LifecycleOwner, and this observer will be notified about modifications
>   of the wrapped data only if the paired LifecycleOwner is in active
>   state.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData